# Check if window contains form

Tags: c#, winforms

I've run in a problem where I have to check if a form with Location X and Y and a width and a height is contained in a rectangle object retrieved from a window with rectangle X, Y, width and height. I have the following code while using winforms. This piece of code should return false if you're outside the borders of the window!

```
if (!(this.Location.Y > rect.Y && this.Location.Y < ((rect.Y + rect.Height) - this.Height)) || !(this.Location.X > rect.X && rect.X < ((this.Location.X + rect.Width) - this.Width)))
```

I'm getting the rectangle by using the follow piece of code:

```
IntPtr hWnd = FindWindow(null, this.windowTitle);
            RECT rect;
            GetWindowRect(hWnd, out rect);
```

Where this is the form and rect is the rectangle object created from the window.

Comment: With "terrible with such things" you mean "terrible at actually asking a question and showing code + data that supports it"?

Comment: Mathematics and such things, is the code supplied not enough? I thought I explained it pretty well...

Comment: Winforms? WPF? What does it mean "doesn't seem to work like it should"?

Comment: You're right! Let me edit the question!

Answer (score 3):

What about:

```
if(!(this.Location.Y > rect.Y && this.Location.X > rect.X && 
   this.Location.X < rect.X + rect.Width && this.Location.Y < rect.Y + rect.Height)){
   //...
}
```

Comment: Fabian Pas tried to implement rectangle.Contains(otherRectangle), not rectangle.Contains(point)...

Comment: @Alexei Not completely right, he wants to check if a form with location x and y is contained in a rectangle. Read the first two lines of the question.

Answer (score 1):

`System.Drawing.Rectangle` class has good methods.  You can use `rectangle1.Contains(rectangle2)`

Comment: I only have one rectangle while the other is a form.

Comment: @FabianPas But your form has x,y,width,and height. enough to form a rectangle.

Comment: Oh yeah! I'll give it a go! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is basically just a matter of coordinate referential.

The less complicated idea would be to use the same function to get both rectangles using the Form.Handle property which is basically a handle just like the one returned by FindWindow:

```
 IntPtr hWnd = FindWindow(null, this.windowTitle);
 RECT rect1;
 GetWindowRect(hWnd, out rect);
 RECT rect2;
 GetWindowRect(form.handle, out rect);
 return rect2.Y >= rect1.Y && rect2.Y + rect2.Height <= rect1.Y + rect1.Height && rect2.X >= rect1.X && rect2.X + rect2.Width <= rect1.X + rect1.Width
```

Comment: I don't actually have two forms, so this won't be possible.

Comment: hmm Ok. Here's another try :p

Comment: Thank you very much for the nice approach although it doesn't really work, it returns false all the time.

Comment: if it doesn't work then it cant be nice. But it should, I might have made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: I think the idea of getting another rectangle was pretty nice so that's why I called it a nice approach, don't be so hard!

Answer (score 1):

For some reason you wanted to write some semi-optimized code -

```
if (!
  (this.Location.Y > rect.Y && 
   this.Location.Y < ((rect.Y + rect.Height) - this.Height))
 || 
  !
  (this.Location.X > rect.X && 
  rect.X < ((this.Location.X + rect.Width) - this.Width)))
```

unfortunately most people can't reason about negate and or is the same statement. You also decided that instead of comparing each corner it is more interesting to compare top/left with some strange combination of opposite corner of other rectangle and size of first rectangle to make condition even more complicated.

Rewriting the same condition with single negate and AND for all sub-conditions will likely be correct and more readable (notice that there were strange non-symmetrical conditions before, now all are very similar):

```
if (!
  (this.Location.Y > rect.Y && 
   this.Location.Y + this.Height < rect.Y + rect.Height &&
   this.Location.X > rect.X && 
   this.Location.X + this.Width < rect.X + rect.Width) 
) {}
```

Comment: This almost seems to work except for the right X boundary.. it doesn't seem to catch the form leaving the window..

Comment: Damn, you're right! I'm sorry! You deserve an upvote too! Ah man, I'm such a mess today!

Comment: It doesn't matter, It happens to me too. ;)

Answer (score 0):

not sure what exactly your asking, but if I understand correctly this should work

```
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(-100,-100, 10, 10);
    if (this.ClientRectangle.IntersectsWith(rect))
    {
        // do stuff
    }
```